# Identifying when a CGContextRef is a PDF context

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

For my Cocoa app I need to know whether a given CGContextRef is a PDF context (as opposed to a bitmap or screen context) in order to take a different rendering path in my CALayer's drawInContext implementation. With the iOS SDK, I can do this with:

```
BOOL isPDF = !CGRectIsEmpty(UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds());
```

But UIGraphics* functions aren't available in the OS X SDK. I was hoping to be able to use:

```
BOOL isPDf = CFGetTypeID(currentContext) != CGContextGetTypeID();
```

But it doesn't seem to hold true, and there is no CGPDFContextGetTypeID() function that returns a type ID specific to PDFs.

Is there any way to identify the type of a given CGContextRef without doing anything nasty like setting static variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API for getting the type of a `CGContextRef`, so you will have to keep this information outside of the context ref itself.

There is an undocumented [CGContextGetType()](http://code.google.com/p/cairogles/source/browse/src/cairo-quartz-surface.c) function that returns the type of the context, see the [CGContextType](http://code.google.com/p/freequartz/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGContextPriv.h) enum for a list of possible values. But you should really not use this.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I afraid of.